# Pytorch identifying batch size as number of channels in Conv2d layer

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I am a total newbie to neural networks using Pytorch to create a VAE model. I've used a bit of tensorflow before, but I have no idea what "in_channels" and "out_channels" are, as arguments to nn.Conv2d/nn.Conv1d.

Disclaimers aside, currently, my model takes in a dataloader with batch size 128 and where each input is a 248 by 46 tensor (so, a 128 x 248 x 46 tensor).

My encoder looks like this right now -- I chopped it down so I could focus on where the error was coming from.

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=248, out_channels=46, kernel_size=(9, 9), stride=(5, 1), padding=(5, 4))

    def forward(self, x):
        print(x.size())
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        return x
```

The Conv2d layer was meant to reduce the 248 by 46 input into a 50 by 46 tensor. However, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [46, 248, 9, 9], expected input[1, 128, 248, 46] to have 248 channels, but got 128 channels instead
```

...even though I print `x.size()` and it displays as `[torch.Size([128, 248, 46])`.

I am unsure a) why the error shows that the layer is adding on an extra dimension to x, and b) whether I am even understanding channels correctly. Should 46 be the real number of channels? Why doesn't Pytorch simply request my input size as a tuple or something, like `in=(248, 46)`?
Or c) if this is an issue with the way I loaded in my data to the model. I have a numpy array `data` of shape `(-1, 248, 46)` and then started training my model as follows.

```
tensor_data = torch.from_numpy(data)
dataset = TensorDataset(tensor_data, tensor_data)
train_dl = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)
...
for epoch in range(20):
     for x_train, y_train in train_loader:
          x_train = x_train.to(device).float()
          optimizer.zero_grad()
          x_pred, mu, log_var = vae(x_train)
          bce_loss = train.BCE(y_train, x_pred)
          kl_loss = train.KL(mu, log_var)
          loss = bce_loss + kl_loss
          loss.backward()
          optimizer.step()
```

Any thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pytorch, `nn.Conv2d` assumes the input (mostly image data) is shaped like: `[B, C_in, H, W]`, where `B` is the batch size, `C_in` is the number of channels, `H` and `W` are the height and width of the image. The output has a similar shape `[B, C_out, H_out, W_out]`. Here, `C_in` and `C_out` are `in_channels` and `out_channels`, respectively. `(H_out, W_out)` is the output image size, which may or may not equal `(H, W)`, depending on the kernel size, the stride and the padding.

However, it is confusing to apply conv2d to reduce `[128, 248, 46]` inputs to `[128, 50, 46]`. Are they image data with height 248 and width 46? If so you can reshape the inputs to `[128, 1, 248, 46]` and use `in_channels = 1` and `out_channels = 1` in conv2d.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you! I realized that it was 1 channel and I should have been using a conv1d layer instead.

Comment: @Racecar Not really, if it was a 1-channel 2D input of size (248, 46), you should use conv2d. If it was a 248-channel 1D input of length 46, you should use conv1d. Although these can be made equivalent if you choose appropriate padding, stride, etc., it's better to use a more accurate description.

Comment: @ihdv By the way, in the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) the valid shape can be also `[C_in, H, W]` (see the `Shape` block).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your model takes a single channel image 28*28 this becomes 784 which is your in_channel and out_channels is the number of classes your model wants to predict

Comment: If I replace in_channels with 248*46, I get `RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [46, 11408, 9, 9], expected input[1, 128, 248, 46] to have 11408 channels, but got 128 channels instead`. Do I have to flatten my input or something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra dimension for the number of channels (1) with the view function. The below code will work!

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=8, kernel_size=(9, 9), stride=(5, 1), padding=(5, 4))

    def forward(self, x):
        print("encoder input size: "+ str(x.shape))
        # x.shape[0] is the number of samples in batches if the number of samples >1, otherwise it is the width
        # (number of samples in a batch, number of channels, width, height)
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], 1, 248,46)
        print("encoder input size after adding 1 channel to shape: "+ str(x.shape))
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        return x

# a test dataset with 128 samples, 248 width and 46 height
test_dataset = torch.rand(128,248,46)
# prints shape of dataset
test.shape

model = Encoder()
model(test_dataset)

# if you are passing only one sample to the model (i.e. to plot) you need to do this instead
test_dataset2 = torch.rand(1,248,46)
model(test_dataset2.view(test_dataset2.shape[0],1,248,46))
```